# CPU-heavy tasks on google compute engine stops running

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to use google compute engine instances to tune a sklearn random forest regressor model with a big dataset. 
I opened a 24-vCPUs/90GB instance (not preemtible) and used n_jobs in code to utilize multiple vCPUs.

I tried to use Jupyter notebook as well as Datalab (google's notebook lab) through ssh to run it, but most of the time the instance just stopped working after about 15 minutes of heavy work (I've tried using 24/24 threads and 18/24 threads both failed). The terminal/shell and lab/notebook interface does not react any more, but the instance seems to continue running from the instance's page. It failed when I tried to reconnect to the instance. Only when I stop and re-start the instance can I connect to it.

I am hoping someone with similar experiences could share with me how should I deal with it? Is there a setting somewhere that prevents heavy-CPU works?

**Update:**

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, 
                           n_iter = 100, cv = 3, random_state=0, 
                           n_jobs = -1, verbose = 11)
rf_random.fit(X_s, y_s)
```

I have find similar questions searching for "sklearn parallel Jupyter freezing". Seems like it's a common problem using n_jobs to parallel with sklearn.

Comment: Do you know why it's crashing/freezing? Is it a memory issue, or something? It's probably a good idea to share at least some of your code.

Comment: Does Stackdriver show any errors?

Comment: "the instance just stopped working...but the instance seems to continue running" - could you provide more explanations regards that contradiction? What is on the page "VM instance details => Monitoring"? Is the instance accessible via serial port? With 100% CPU utilization an OS could keep running your code but respond with significant delays, no matter GCE VM instance or bare metal server.